# Randomly split up elements from a stream of data without knowing the total number of elements

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random, split, data-science

Given a "split ratio", I am trying to randomly split up a dataset into two groups. The catch is, that I do not know beforehand how many items the dataset contains. My library receives the data one by one from an input stream and is expected to return the data to two output streams. The resulting two datasets should ideally be exactly split into the given split ratio.

**Illustration:**

```
                            ┌─► stream A
 input stream ──► LIBRARY ──┤
                            └─► stream B
```

For example, given a split ratio of `30/70`, stream A would be expected to receive 30% of the elements from the input stream and stream B the remaining 70%. The order must remain.

---

### My ideas so far:

**Idea 1: "Roll the dice" for each element**

The obvious approach: For each element the algorithm randomly decides if the element should go into stream A or B. The problem is, that the resulting data sets might be far off from the expected split ratio. Given a split ratio of `50/50`, the resulting data split might be something far off (could even be `100/0` for very small data sets). The goal is to keep the resulting split ratio as close as possible to the desired split ratio.

**Idea 2: Use a cache and randomize the cached data**

Another idea is to cache a fixed number of elements before passing them on. This would result in caching 1000 elements and shuffling the data (or their corresponding indices to keep the order stable), splitting them up and passing the resulting data sets on. This should work very well, but I'm unsure if the randomization is really random for large data sets (I imagine there will patterns when looking at the distribution).

Both algorithms are not optimal, so I hope you can help me.

---

**Background**

This is about a layer-based data science tool, where each layer receives data from the previous layer via a stream. This layer is expected to split the data (vectors) up into a training and test set before passing them on. The input data can range from just a few elements to a never ending stream of data (hence, the streams). The code is developed in JavaScript, but this question is more about the algorithm than the actual implementation.

Comment: Reading your question and throwing you my first hint without overthinking it : each time you receive X lines. You check the dataset A and B for there number and calculate the ratio. According to this ratio and the expected ratio, define how you have to split you X lines in order to match the expected ratio ?

Comment: It's quite hard to maintain randomness here. You don't know the full scope, you still have to predict how many items you will have in order to maintain the ratio. At some point you might have walked too far from your expected ratio and then have to balance the flow. This breaks randomness. You might consider having a weight defined by the current ratio I proposed ? It could maintain randomness and redirect the flow a bit more. Still predictable... But a bit less. I understand what you are trying to achieve and I would like to know the answer if there is one.

Comment: Nice question format by the way :)

Comment: do you want an exact split on those ratios or thats just the probability it should keep for each stream?

Comment: @juvian If possible, the ratio should be met exactly, but I'm not sure if that is even possible, that's why I left it kind of open in the question. I'm still reading your answer and trying to understand it btw ;)

Comment: I did not make an answer yet :P. Trying to understand the one from @junvar as well to see if its the same as what I thought...

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of your second idea, randomly shuffling fixed size batches of cached data. Indeed it would not be completey random unless you cache all the data. This is because each stream would end up with items from each batch, which would make certain data splits, e.g. where A ends up with the last 30%, impossible.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf : what did you end up with on this? I am curious ...

Comment: @GregorOphey None of the answer really satisfied my needs (mainly regarding the "exact split"). So in the end, I changed my application. It now passes the number of elements though the layers.

Answer (score 6):

You could adjust the probability as it shifts away from the desired rate.

Here's an example along with tests for various levels of adjusting the probability. As we increase the adjustments, we see the stream splitter deviates less from the ideal ratio, but it also means its less random (knowing the previous values, you can predict the next values).

```js
// rateStrictness = 0 will lead to "rolling the dice" for each invocations
// higher values of rateStrictness will lead to strong "correcting" forces
function* splitter(desiredARate, rateStrictness = .5) {
 let aCount = 0, bCount = 0;

 while (true) {

  let actualARate = aCount / (aCount + bCount);
  let aRate = desiredARate + (desiredARate - actualARate) * rateStrictness;
  if (Math.random() < aRate) {
   aCount++;
   yield 'a';
  } else {
   bCount++;
   yield 'b';
  }
 }
}

let test = (desiredARate, rateStrictness) => {
 let s = splitter(desiredARate, rateStrictness);
 let values = [...Array(1000)].map(() => s.next().value);
 let aCount = values.map((_, i) => values.reduce((count, v, j) => count + (v === 'a' && j <= i), 0));
 let aRate = aCount.map((c, i) => c / (i + 1));
 let deviation = aRate.map(a => a - desiredARate);
 let avgDeviation = deviation.reduce((sum, dev) => sum + dev, 0) / deviation.length;
 console.log(`inputs: desiredARate = ${desiredARate}; rateStrictness = ${rateStrictness}; average deviation = ${avgDeviation}`);
};

test(.5, 0);
test(.5, .25);
test(.5, .5);
test(.5, .75);
test(.5, 1);
test(.5, 10);
test(.5, 100);
```

Comment: This algorithm also does not work very well with small datasets. But it's a nice improvement over my first approach. Thanks :)

Comment: I think small samples are problematic for all random sampling.

Comment: You are probably right. I'm still hoping for an algorithm that somehow solves this problem and is able to keep the ratio perfectly...

Answer (score 1):

How about rolling the dice twice: First of all decide wether the stream should be chosen randomly or if the ratio should be taken into account. Then for the first case, roll the dice, for the second case take the ratio. Some pseudocode:

```
  const toA =
    Math.random() > 0.5 // 1 -> totally random, 0 -> totally equally distributed
      ? Math.random() > 0.7
      :  (numberA / (numberA + numberB) > 0.7);
```

That's just an idea I came up with, I haven't tried that ...

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I am not sure I get it. Why do you use `0.7`? Shouldn't it be `0.5` (in case of `Math.random() > 0.5`) and `1.0` (in the other case)?

Comment: Thats from "For example, given a split ratio of 30/70, stream A would be expected to receive 30%"

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have to maintain a given ratio R for data items going to stream A, e.g. R = 0.3 as per your example. Then on receiving each data item count the
total number of items and the items passed on to stream A and decide for each item if it goes to A based on what choice keeps you closer to your target ratio R.

That should be about the best you can do for any size of the data set. As for randomness the resulting streams A and B should be about as random as your input stream.

Let's see how this plays out for the first couple of iterations:

Example: R = 0.3

N : total number of items processed so far (initially 0)

A : numbers passed on to stream A so far (initially 0)

First Iteration

```
N = 0 ; A = 0 ; R = 0.3
if next item goes to stream A then 
    n = N + 1
    a = A + 1
    r = a / n = 1
else if next item goes to stream B
    n = N + 1
    a  = A
    r = a / n = 0

So first item goes to stream B since 0 is closer to 0.3
```

Second Iteration

```
N = 1 ; A = 0 ; R = 0.3
if next item goes to stream A then 
    n = N + 1
    a = A + 1
    r = a / n = 0.5
else if next item goes to stream B
    n = N + 1
    a = A
    r = a / n = 0

So second item goes to stream A since 0.5 is closer to 0.3
```

Third Iteration

```
N = 2 ; A = 1 ; R = 0.3
if next item goes to stream A then 
    n = N + 1
    a = A + 1
    r = a / n = 0.66
else if next item goes to stream B
    n = N + 1
    a = A
    r = a / n = 0.5

So third item goes to stream B since 0.5 is closer to 0.3
```

Fourth Iteration

```
N = 3 ; A = 1 ; R = 0.3
if next item goes to stream A then 
    n = N + 1
    a = A + 1
    r = a / n = 0.5
else if next item goes to stream B
    n = N + 1
    a = A
    r = a / n = 0.25

So third item goes to stream B since 0.25 is closer to 0.3
```

So this here would be the pseudo code for deciding each data item:

```
if (((A + 1) / (N + 1)) - R) < ((A / (N + 1)) - R ) then
    put the next data item on stream A
    A = A + 1
    N = N + 1
 else
    put the next data item on B
    N = N + 1
```

As discussed in the comments below, that is not random in the sense intended by the OP. So once we know the correct target stream for the next item we flip a coin to decide if we actually put it there, or introduce an error.

```
if (((A + 1) / (N + 1)) - R) < ((A / (N + 1)) - R ) then
    target_stream = A
else 
    target_stream = B

if random() < 0.5 then
    if target_stream == A then
        target_stream = B
    else
        target_stream = A

if target_stream == A then   
    put the next data item on stream A
    A = A + 1
    N = N + 1
 else
    put the next data item on B
    N = N + 1
```

Now that could lead to an arbitrarily large error overall. So we have to set an error limit L and check how far off the resulting ratio is from the target R when errors are about to be introduced:

```
if (((A + 1) / (N + 1)) - R) < ((A / (N + 1)) - R ) then
    target_stream = A
else 
    target_stream = B

if random() < 0.5 then
    if target_stream == A then
        if abs((A / (N + 1)) - R) < L then
            target_stream = B
    else
        if abs(((A + 1) / (N + 1)) - R) < L then
            target_stream = A

if target_stream == A then   
    put the next data item on stream A
    A = A + 1
    N = N + 1
 else
    put the next data item on B
    N = N + 1
```

So here we have it: Processing data items one by one we know the correct stream to put the next item on, then we introduce random local errors and we are able to limit the overall error with L.

Comment: This will keep the ratio optimal but there is no randomness here, right? If I run the algorithm twice, the results are the same.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf: True, running twice with the same input stream would give same results. That would even be true when introducing (pseudo) randomness unless you change the seed value. In any case I would treat introducing randomness and keeping the ratio as separate concerns. In this case (i.e. one by one processing of data items) it turns out that they are conflicting concerns and you have to make a trade off decision. This could be mitigated by processing the data items in batches of meaningful size,  say one hundred items.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf : I updated my answer by adding randomness and error control. Sorry that it's not in javascript ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that combines both of your ideas: It uses a cache. As long as the amount of elements in cache can handle that if the stream ends, we can still approach target distribution, we just roll a dice. If not, we add it to the cache. When input stream ends, we shuffle elements in cache and send them trying to approach distribution. I am not sure if there is any gain in this over just forcing element to go to x if distribution is straying off too much in terms of randomness.

Beware that this approach does not preserve order from original input stream. A few other things could be added such as cache limit and relaxing distribution error (using 0 here). If you need to preserve order, it can be done by sending cache value and pushing to cache current one instead of just sending current one when there are still elements in cache.

```js
let shuffle = (array) => array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

function* generator(numElements) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numElements;i++) yield i; 
}

function* splitter(aGroupRate, generator) {
  let cache = [];
  let sentToA = 0;
  let sentToB = 0;
  let bGroupRate = 1 - aGroupRate;
  let maxCacheSize = 0;
  
  let sendValue = (value, group) => {
      sentToA += group == 0;
      sentToB += group == 1;
      return {value: value, group: group};
  }
  
  function* retRandomGroup(value, expected) {
    while(Math.random() > aGroupRate != expected) {
      if (cache.length) {
        yield sendValue(cache.pop(), !expected);
      } else {
        yield sendValue(value, !expected);
        return;
      } 
    }
    yield sendValue(value, expected);
  }
  
  for (let value of generator) {
    if (sentToA + sentToB == 0) {
      yield sendValue(value, Math.random() > aGroupRate);
      continue;
    }
    
    let currentRateA = sentToA / (sentToA + sentToB);
        
    if (currentRateA <= aGroupRate) {
      // can we handle current value going to b group?
      if ((sentToA + cache.length) / (sentToB + sentToA + 1 + cache.length) >= aGroupRate) {
        for (val of retRandomGroup(value, 1)) yield val;
        continue;
      }
    }
    
    if (currentRateA > aGroupRate) {
      // can we handle current value going to a group?
      if (sentToA / (sentToB + sentToA + 1 + cache.length) <= aGroupRate) {
        for (val of retRandomGroup(value, 0)) yield val;
        continue;
      }
    }  
    
    cache.push(value);
    maxCacheSize = Math.max(maxCacheSize, cache.length)
  }
  
  shuffle(cache);
  
  let totalElements = sentToA + sentToB + cache.length;
  
  while (sentToA < totalElements * aGroupRate) {
    yield {value: cache.pop(), group: 0}
    sentToA += 1;
  }
  
  while (cache.length) {
    yield {value: cache.pop(), group: 1}
  }  
  
  yield {cache: maxCacheSize}
}

function test(numElements, aGroupRate) {
  let gen = generator(numElements);
  let sentToA = 0;
  let total = 0;
  let cacheSize = null;
  let split = splitter(aGroupRate, gen);
  for (let val of split) {
    if (val.cache != null) cacheSize = val.cache;
    else {
      sentToA += val.group == 0;
      total += 1
    }
  }
  console.log("required rate for A group", aGroupRate, "actual rate", sentToA / total, "cache size used", cacheSize);
}

test(3000, 0.3)
test(5000, 0.5)
test(7000, 0.7)
```

Comment: @ThomasDondorf any comments on my answer?

Comment: Tried to understand the code and failed (sorry, I will give it another try..), but I got the idea from your explanation (I hope). Do I understand correctly that when the stream ends, the remaining cache will be put into group A or B to meet the ratio? I guess this will make the ending of the stream non-random then?

Comment: That is correct. For every input from the stream, you check your current rates (how much you already sent to each group). Then you consider the worst case: that if you use random to choose a group, it will go to the already unbalanced group (straying the current rate even farther away than desired). If your cache has enough elements to be able to handle it later, it is allowed. If not, its just thrown into cache and keep processing. When the stream ends, you will most likely have a not perfect rate. Remaining cache elements will be set to fix that, in most cases putting all in same group.

Comment: I like that this algorithm meets the ratio, I'm just not sure if this approach is much better than idea 2 regarding the randomness. Instead of having an overall not-that-great randomness (idea 2), you have great randomness at runtime with your approach, but basically no randomness at the end of the stream.

Comment: Order from input stream is not preserved, so its not that the ending of the stream will be non random. The part non random is the elements that remained in the cache. However, which elements end up there is quite random. Even if something goes to cache (which will be usually the case for the first few elements), the retRandomGroup implementation makes it more random: when we have enough elements in cache to handle a worst case, instead of directly sending current value from input, we actually check if the group will indeed be that worst case. If it wasnt, we can instead send element from cache

Comment: Did some tests and it still seems biased to some groupings, will try to improve it later

Comment: @ThomasDondorf from what I could find, reservoir sampling is similar to what you want, but that assumes a known amount of items you want to sample instead of a distribution. There is [this paper](http://www.inf.ufpr.br/eduardo/papers/SBBD15_Tiago.pdf) that deals with distribution instead, but I have tried it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/juvian/6ueqzoph/25/) and it seems more biased towards half of the elements. Not sure if that is an error on the paper or not. You could try to implement [this one](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1550147718773999) instead which is more recent

Comment: Tried many things myself but nothing beats the jsfiddle I linked. Just note that the probability needs to be <= 0.5 or it wont work well (switch groups if you need > 0.5). Still, that newer recent paper should give better results if you want to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the two numbers you wrote (chunk size of 1000, probability split of 0.7) you might not have any problem with the simple approach of just rolling the dice for every element.
Talking about probability and high numbers, you have the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

This means, that you do have a risk of splitting the streams very unevenly into 0 and 1000 elements, but in practice this is veeery unlikely to happen. As you are talking about testing and training sets I also do not expect your probability split to be far off of 0.7. And in case you are allowed to cache, you can still use this for the first 100 elements, so that you are sure to have enough data for the law of large numbers to kick in.

This is the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) for n=1000, p=.7
[image]

In case you want to reproduce the image with other parameters

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import binom
index = np.arange(binom.ppf(0.01, n, p), binom.ppf(0.99, n, p))
pd.Series(index=index, data=binom.pmf(x, n, p)).plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: My concern is more about a user using the tool to split the data (for example `50/50`) and then noticing that for 100 input samples, the tool ended up splitting them `49/51`. Even if that is very close to `50/50` this could cause a lot of confusion for the end user. That's why I'm looking for a better solution.